# Zooming object in GLES20

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0

I have a problem.

When i execute this code at the first time :

```
...
restoreMatrix(currentScaleMatrix);
Matrix.translateM(currentScaleMatrix, 0, 0f, mGLSceneHeight / 2, 0f);
Matrix.translateM(currentScaleMatrix, 0, mFocalPoint.x, mFocalPoint.y, 0f);
Matrix.scaleM(currentScaleMatrix, 0, mCurrentScaleFactor, mCurrentScaleFactor, 1f);
Matrix.translateM(currentScaleMatrix, 0, -mFocalPoint.x, -mFocalPoint.y, 0f);
Matrix.translateM(currentScaleMatrix, 0, 0f, -mGLSceneHeight / 2, 0f);
//Draw
```

I have a good result in point what i have. But after second time, mFocalPoint is calculated wrong, but i can't understand why.

```
private void restoreMatrix(float[] previewMVPMatrix) {
    synchronized (pathStack) {
        for (Path path : pathStack) {
            Matrix.translateM(previewMVPMatrix, 0, 0f, mGLSceneHeight / 2, 0f);

            Matrix.translateM(previewMVPMatrix, 0, path.point.x, path.point.y, 0f);
            Matrix.scaleM(previewMVPMatrix, 0, path.scaleFactor, path.scaleFactor, 1f);
            Matrix.translateM(previewMVPMatrix, 0, -path.point.x, -path.point.y, 0f);

            Matrix.translateM(previewMVPMatrix, 0, 0f, -mGLSceneHeight / 2, 0f);
        }
    }
}

public boolean onScaleBegin(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
    float glX = (detector.getFocusX() * (mScaleFactorX)) - mGLSceneWidth / 2 ;
    float glY = (detector.getFocusY() * (mScaleFactorY)) - mGLSceneHeight / 2;
    mFocalPoint = new PointF((glX/ realCurrentScaleFactor), (-glY / realCurrentScaleFactor));
    return true;
}

public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
    mCurrentScaleFactor *= detector.getScaleFactor();
    return true;
}

public void onScaleEnd(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
   updateMatrix(mFocalPoint, mCurrentScaleFactor);
    mFocalPoint = new PointF(0f, 0f);
    mCurrentScaleFactor = 1f;
}

private float getRealCurrentScaleFactor() {
    float scaleFactor = 1f; // by default
    for (Path path : pathStack) {
        scaleFactor*=path.scaleFactor;
    }
    Log.d("Scaler","[Scale sum] :: "+scaleFactor);
    return scaleFactor;
}
```

---

**So** the **question is : How to calculate `FocalPoint` in Zoomed Image?**

Answer (score 0):

Actually i found what the problem. Focal point calculated right. You just need :

- save `actualMatrix` to `oldMatrix` (Matrix from first zoom)
- reset `actualMatrix`
- doing zoom on new **identity** `actualMatrix`
- multiply `oldMatrix * actualMatrix`

> Matrix.setIdentityM(oldMatrix, 0); // initialize old matrix in constructor

---

> #### onScale()
>
> ```
> Matrix.translateM(actualMatrix, 0, focusX, focusY, 0);<br>
> Matrix.scaleM(actualMatrix, 0, scaleFactor, scaleFactor, 0);<br>
> Matrix.translateM(actualMatrix, 0, -focusX, -focusY, 0);<br>
> ```

---

> #### onScaleEnd()
>
> ```
> Matrix.multiplyMM(oldMatrix, 0, actualMatrix, 0, oldMatrix, 0);
> Matrix.setIdentity(actualMatrix,0);
> ```